# font packaging in visual studio 2008

Tags: html, .net, fonts, packaging

I created a website(actually a single HTML Page!)in visual studio 2008 as a part of learning.
I used some fonts in it which is not pre-installed in windows XP.
So when I run the webpage in another system, all those fonts where not displayed.
So is there any way to package fonts with webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serious web development you should look into webfonts (eg. google webfonts, or any other otf webfont that you upload to your server) to keep the compatibility high and the request file size low.

Webfonts are used with the CSS @font-face rule.

http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern web development. There are numerous providers and utilities including [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) as well as [commercial](http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts) [vendors](https://www.typotheque.com/webfonts/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few methods you can try.

http://jonraasch.com/blog/embedding-custom-fonts